Avoiding errors 429 when building a chrome extension
I'm building my first chrome extension using html and js - a simple popup window with a user input form, which detects the language, and then translates to japanese if the input is in english or to english if the input is in japanese.
The function I've built for this works when I run it locally on node, but not when I "render" the full extension through localhost or as an extension on chrome. I think I'm getting an error 429 for too many requests to the google translate api, but I've only been able to see this message once.
`import { translate } from '@vitalets/google-translate-api';

const inputLang = "en";
const outputLang = "ja";

// Translation
async function fetchAndTranslate(inputString) {
  try {
    let response = await translate(inputString, { to: 'ja', fetchOptions: { agent } });
    if (response.raw.src === "ja") {
      inputLang = "ja";
      outputLang = "en";
      response = await translate(inputString, { to: 'en', fetchOptions: { agent } });
    }
    else {
      inputLang = response.raw.src;
      outputLang = "ja";
    }
    const returnString = response.text;
    updateFlags();
    return returnString;
  } catch (e) {
   if (e.name === 'TooManyRequestsError') {
      console.log('Error 429: Too many requests. Switching to new proxy.');
    }
  }
}`

I've seen a guide online for getting and cycling through a list of google translate compatible proxies, but that seems like a lot of work for something which I'm not sure will fix my issue. I'm looking for some insight from more experienced web devs.
